# Cannot access a running docker container via public DNS on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I want to run my Angular Webapp on an AWS EC2 instance. I created a Dockerfile in my Angular project and deployed it to the EC2 instance. Gitlab CI creates the Angular project and the Docker image. It executes the container with `sudo docker run --name frontend -d -p 80:8080 registry.gitlab.com/.../frontend`. If I now want to access the webapp via the public URL the following error occurs:

> This webpage is not available. {ip}.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com has rejected the connection.

How can I make my Webapp public?

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:latest as node
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
RUN ng build

FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=node /app/dist/frontend /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 8080
```

Tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

gitlab-ci.yml

```
production-build:
  stage: angular-build
  image: trion/ng-cli
  before_script:
    - npm ci
  script:
    - ng build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist/

docker-build:
  stage: docker-build
  script:
    - docker build -t registry.gitlab.com/.../frontend .
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN registry.gitlab.com
    - docker push registry.gitlab.com/.../frontend
```

EC2 inbound rules

[image]

**Update**

[image]

Comment: when you hit `curl localhost:80`, does it returns the web page?

Comment: No there is an error: curl: (52) empty reply from server

Answer (score 1):

This is probably related to your output dir, so when you copy `/app/dist/frontend` to `/usr/share/nginx/html`, there is no index.html inside the html folder, but another folder instead. Try to get into the container and run `ls /usr/share/nginx/html` to check if this afirmation is correct, and after that you will be able solve the problem!

Comment: Thanks, I checked the docker dir and it contains the correct index file. I've updated my question.

Comment: So, as my last guess, I would check the nginx config file to see which directory it's serving... If you are using Ubuntu it could be `/var/www/html`